# State true or false ( I am not sure what i did wrong)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

1. For , ∈ ℝ, we have ‖−‖≤‖+‖.
2. The dot product of two vectors is a vector.
3. For ,∈ℝ, we have ‖−‖≤‖‖+‖‖.
4. A homogeneous system of linear equations with more equations than variables will always have at least one parameter in its solution.
5. Given a non-zero vector , there exist exactly two unit vectors that are parallel to .

My answers were

1. FALSE 
   because if we assumed that a= (-1,-2) and b= (3,4) it would make the statement false
2. FALSE
   because the dot product of 2 vectors is a scalar
3. FALSE
   this would have the same assumption as for question 1
4. FALSE
   I am not sure
5. TRUE 
   I am not sure

I am not sure which one of my answers is/are wrong

Comment: Look at 3, call $-{\bf v} = {\bf w}$ and look up the triangle inequality.

Comment: wouldn't it be the same for question 1 since the triangle inequality states that  ‖+‖ ≤ ‖‖+‖‖?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ and $2$ are both right.

$3$ is wrong. The triangle inequality actually implies $3$:

$$||u-v||\leq ||u||+||-v||=||u||+||v||$$

$4$ is right. Just consider

$$\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
    x=0 \\
    x=0
    \end{array}
    \right.$$
The only solution is $x=0$. This statement would be true the other way around: a homogeneous system of linear equations with more variables than equations will always have at least one parameter in its solution.

And $5$ is also right: $\bf u=\frac{v}{||v||}$ is a unit vector. Any other vector parallel to  $\bf v$ (and thus also parallel to $\bf u$) is of the form $k\bf u$ for some real number $k$. And $k\bf u$ is a unit vector if and only if $k=\pm 1$. Hence the two unit vectors are $\pm \bf u$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Number 3 is incorrect. Why? Because of the well-known fact that $|\bf{x} + \bf{y}| \le |\bf{x}| + |\bf{y}|$ (the Triangle Inequality).

In particular, $|\bf{u} - \bf{v}| = |\bf{u} + (- \bf{v})| \le |\bf{u}| + |- \bf{v}| = |\bf{u}| + |\bf{v}|$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation